# Removing a dictionary from a list nested inside another dictionary based on difference in date

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the format of

```
test = {
    "A": [
      {
        "sourceName": "MongoDB",
        "Date": "2020-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
        "sourceName": "Dynamo",
        "Date": "2020-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
        "sourceName": "Dynamo",
        "Date": "2020-12-09T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    ],
    "B": [
      {
        "sourceName": "MongoDB",
        "Date": "2020-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
        "sourceName": "SQL",
        "Date": "2020-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
        "sourceName": "Dynamo",
        "Date": "2020-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    ]
  };
```

I am trying to remove the dictionary within the list  where for key '**sourceName**' have occurred more then once and key '**Date** have newer date as value.

For example, in the above given scenario, for key "**A**", there are multiple instances of Dynamo,so the dictionary element

```
      {
        "sourceName": "Dynamo",
        "Date": "2020-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
        "sourceName": "Dynamo",
        "Date": "2020-12-09T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
```

the final resulting dictionary should only contain

```
      {
        "sourceName": "Dynamo",
        "Date": "2020-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
```

out of the two. The final result should look like this.

```
{
    "A": [
      {
        "sourceName": "MongoDB",
        "Date": "2020-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
        "sourceName": "Dynamo",
        "Date": "2020-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    ],
    "B": [
      {
        "sourceName": "MongoDB",
        "Date": "2020-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
        "sourceName": "SQL",
        "Date": "2020-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
        "sourceName": "Dynamo",
        "Date": "2020-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    ]
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pandas to sort and remove duplicates, then convert back to dictionary

eg:

```
import pandas as pd
test_new = {}

for t in test:
    test_new[t]=pd.DataFrame(test[t]).sort_values('Date').drop_duplicates('sourceName', keep="first").to_dict('records')

print(test_new)
```

explanation:  for each category, convert list of dictionaries to pandas DataFrame, sort on dates, and then drop duplicate sourceNames, keeping earlier date.  Then convert DataFrame back to list of dictionaries.

output:

```
{'A': [{'sourceName': 'MongoDB', 'Date': '2020-11-10T00:00:00.000Z'},
  {'sourceName': 'Dynamo', 'Date': '2020-11-10T00:00:00.000Z'}],
 'B': [{'sourceName': 'MongoDB', 'Date': '2020-11-10T00:00:00.000Z'},
  {'sourceName': 'SQL', 'Date': '2020-11-10T00:00:00.000Z'},
  {'sourceName': 'Dynamo', 'Date': '2020-11-10T00:00:00.000Z'}]}
```